# Find features/cmdlets not supported in PowerShell V2

Tags: powershell

I work on automation using PowerShell scripts for our clients. The client base involves different servers of Windows OS some use PowerShell v2.0 and few are using latter versions including v3.0 and higher.

While writing scripts I am using PowerShell V3.0 due to its fancy ISE and intellisense features. However, in some cases scripts work well on my machine and fail on the client machines since they are using v2.0. I need to find some way to make it compatible with v2.0 by changing the code again.

I am looking for some way to find out all the alternative ways for the features that work on v3.0 but not on v2.0. For example -in and -notin are not supported on v2.0, and I found some workaround on this site for using -contains and -notcontains.

Can someone direct me to a place to refer where I can find all such workarounds or at least the list of features that are not supported on v2.0 vs. v3.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found one link with this information. Please share any similar links you may have:
[TechNet Wiki Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4788.powershell-v3-tips-and-tricks-what-s-new-in-v3.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant really suggest off site resources as that would not make for a good answer. Also haven't found a good dupe for this generalization either.

There is a way that I can suggest help you get the newer features out of your code. While you are coding in 3.0, with features that I would miss if I didn't have them, you can test your code by [running PowerShell with the `-Version`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847899.aspx) switch

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 5d9a91b4-e984-43a5-823e-e20bb8f9e30a
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace



PS C:\Users\mcameron> powershell -version 2
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\mcameron> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : c3a6fe5c-295e-440b-8433-2f2b87741706
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

So my suggestion here is test your code in the lower version. If/When it breaks you can troubleshoot those individual parts. If you still are stuck it could be another good question to ask.